# Apache velocity unable to find resource

Tags: java, apache, plugins, velocity, rcp

I am trying to load a template with velocity. The only thing I have is the path of a file. but I can't seem to load the File with this absolute path. How do you need to do this?

The documentation is very fuzzy about reading absolute templates....

I am trying to use this in a plug-in for an RCP program

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your best option is to look at the Resource Loader concept in Velocity. This is the way that Velocity provides for loading templates from arbitrary sources. See the documentation [here](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/developer-guide.html#Configuring_Resource_Loaders) for details.

You can look at the available ones for reference how they do it. There is a [FileResourceLoader](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/FileResourceLoader.html) which probably does exactly what you need if configured properly.

If that does not work, you can derive from the base [ResourceLoader](http://velocity.apache.org/engine/releases/velocity-1.7/apidocs/org/apache/velocity/runtime/resource/loader/ResourceLoader.html) class. Your ResourceLoader would then simply map from the name that you pass to the getTemplate()-call to the actual file.

Comment: If you derive from the ResourceLoader class can you also load multiple templates from different folder locations?

Comment: Sure, you can build the loader any way you want, it receives a string and needs to return the corresponding InputStream.

Answer (score 1):

put your templates in folder  "templates/template1.vt" in your plugin project and make sure you add this folder in build.properties. you can try to get the template file either of the ways below.

```
one:
 URL url= Activator.getDefault().getBundle().getEntry("templates/template1.vt");
 url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
 File file = new File(url.toURI());

second:
url = new URL("platform:/plugin/<plugin id>/templates/template1.vt");
url = FileLocator.toFileURL(url);
File file = new File(url.toURI());
```

Comment: It has to be a folder outside my plug-in! The only way I can manage to do this is when I set the Fileloader property in velocity... and let Velocity make the INIT with this path... BUT I have multiple templates at different locations... that's the real problem :/ now I have to initialize my Velocity over and over again with different properties